# Complexity of $L[\mathrm{cf}]$

Tags: lo.logic, set-theory, inner-model-theory

Assuming large cardinal axioms, which real numbers are in $L[\mathrm{cf}]$, where $\mathrm{cf}$ is the cofinality function on ordinals?

$L[\mathrm{cf}]$ is the minimal inner model that 'knows' the cofinality of every ordinal in V, or more precisely, $∀α\,\{(β,\mathrm{cf}(β)):β<α\}∈L[\mathrm{cf}]$. Cofinality in $L[\mathrm{cf}]$ need not equal cofinality in $V$.

I have a solution to a simpler problem:
*Theorem:* A real number is in $L$[Card] iff it is in the minimal inner model with a proper class of measurable cardinals (assuming the sharp for this model exists).  Here, Card is the cardinality function.
*Corollary* (under the same assumption): The theory of $(L[\mathrm{Card}],∈,\mathrm{Card})$ is $Δ^1_3$.
*Proof sketch of the theorem:*  Starting with the minimal inner model $M$ with a proper class of measurable cardinals, iterate the first measurable cardinal until it becomes $ω_1^V$, the second until it becomes $ω_2^V$, and so on for every regular successor cardinal in $V$.  For the converse, every $ω_{α+ω}$ can be shown to be measurable in HOD<sup>*L*[Card]</sup> with $\{ω_{α+1}, ω_{α+2}, ω_{α+3}, ...\}$ Prikry generic over HOD<sup>*L*[Card]</sup>.
*Additional details on the proof:*  If $M$ is iterated until we get $M'$ with measurable cardinals matching regular $V$-cardinals except that the next measurable cardinal after $ω_α^V$ is $ω_{α+ω}^V$, then $S = (ω_{α+1},ω_{α+2},...)$ is Prikry generic over $M'$ since if a measurable cardinal is iterated, a cofinal sequence of length $ω$ of its past values is Prikry generic. Now, $\mathrm{HOD}^{L[\mathrm{Card}]}⊂\mathrm{HOD}^{M'[S]}=M'$ and $S∈L[\mathrm{Card}]$, so $S$ is also Prikry generic over $\mathrm{HOD}^{L[\mathrm{Card}]}$.

For the cofinality problem, my conjecture is to use a model $M$ (closely related to $L[\mathrm{cf}]$) such that:
nonmeasurable regular cardinals in $M$ have $V$-cofinality $ω$,
measurable cardinals of order $α$ in $M$ have $V$-cofinality $ω_{α+1}$ (or $ω_α$ if $α$ is weakly inaccessible (in $V$) plus a finite ordinal),
and $M$ is obtained by iterating away the least mouse with a measure concentrating on cardinals with $o(κ)=κ$, and iterating the measures until the above correspondences hold.  However, I do not know whether this works, or for that matter, whether the theory of $L[\mathrm{cf}]$ is generically absolute.

An extension of the problem is to set $\mathrm{cf}(κ)=κ+α$ iff $κ$ is weakly $α$-Mahlo, which is well-defined for $α≤κ^+$.  A $κ^+$-Mahlo $κ$ is called greatly Mahlo.  For comparison, a limit ordinal $κ$ has cofinality $≥α$ iff for every (infinite) regular $β<α$, ordinals of cofinality $β$ are stationary below $κ$.  (Also, if singular $κ$ pose a problem, I would be happy to see a solution for this extension with $\mathrm{cf}(κ)$ restricted to regular $κ$.) It appears plausible that the construction using orders of measurability can be extended to this problem, with weakly greatly Mahlo cardinals corresponding to $M$-cardinals that are strong up to a measurable.  If that is the case, then under large cardinal axioms, all reals in $L[\mathrm{cf}]$ are still $Δ^1_3$.

Answer (score 5):

Дмитро, can you expand a bit on how you prove that every ℵ<sub>α+ω</sub> is measurable in the HOD of L[Card] and why the sequence of the ℵ<sub>α+n</sub>s is Prikry generic, assuming there is a sharp for an inner model with a proper class of measurable cardinals? Thanks, Ralf. Regardless of that, the result is correct: if L[Card] doesn't have an inner model with a proper class of measurable cardinals, then we may compare K<sup>L[Card]</sup> with the sharp for an inner model with a proper class of measurable cardinals; a half-open interval from Card may then be used to produce a measure on an iterate of K<sup>L[Card]</sup> which may be pulled back to K<sup>L[Card]</sup>; this measure is in L[Card], which gives a contradiction. 
Your question about the complexity of the reals of L[cf] is related to the question: which reals does C* have (where C* is the least inner model which knows which ordinals have countable cofinality)? Magidor showed C* has 0<sup>†</sup> and more, and with him I showed (assuming a measurable cardinal above a Woodin cardinal in V) that all the reals of C* are in M<sub>1</sub>, the least inner model with one Wodin cardinal (so that K<sup>C*</sup> exists and is 1-small).

Comment: That should probably go in the comments, not the answers. There's an "Add a comment" below the body of the question, clicking on that would let you add a comment. Also, you can use LaTeX syntax with dollar symbols to get $\aleph_\alpha$.

Comment: Too late. Next time.

Comment: Thank you.  I added more details; let me know whether the argument works.  Can you include a link to the paper(s) about C* ?

Comment: See  https://www.newton.ac.uk/files/preprints/ni16006.pdf  . The above result is mentioned on p.38. If you want, I could try to write down some details here.

Comment: Oh, I found a note on it:  https://ivv5hpp.uni-muenster.de/u/rds/note_on_Cstar.pdf . And, yes, your additional details to the proof look okay to me.