# Cardinal Register Machines

Tags: lo.logic, set-theory, computability-theory

A cardinal register machine is like an ordinal register machine but with branching based on cardinal equality rather than ordinal equality.  What is the complexity of the halting problem for cardinal register machines (with finite initial values in the registers)?

Is the complexity independent of whether
- at limits, the internal state is set to the initial state versus liminf (the registers always use liminf as ordinals)
- we can test for ordinal equality in addition to cardinal equality
- we have a copy instruction that allows copying register A into register B (without it, we may have to zero B first which affects liminf)?

Also, what if computations were restricted to countable length?

Ordinal register machines are a model of transfinite computation with a finite set of internal states and a finite set of registers that can store arbitrary ordinals.  They are explored in "[Computing the Recursive Truth Predicate on Ordinal Register Machines](http://www.math.uni-bonn.de/people/koepke/Preprints/Computing_the_recursive_truth_predicate_on_ordinal_register_machines.pdf)" by Peter Koepke and Ryan Siders.

For readers unfamiliar with ordinal register machines or wondering why we would want the restrictions above, the answer is that cardinal register machines have a natural definition that scarcely makes any use of set theory.

*(Mostly) nontechnical definition:*
A cardinal register machine is like a finite register machine:
* Finite internal state (i.e. finite set of internal states).
* Finite set of registers.
* The ability to
   - halt
   - zero a register
   - increment: add a new element to a register
   - test whether two registers have the same number of elements
*but with a twist:*
* The machine can run for a transfinite time. At limit steps,
   - the internal state is set to the initial state
   - each register keeps the elements added since the supremum of times it was zeroed.

Thus, each register stores a set of elements, with the ability to add a new element (elements are never repeated), remove all elements, and test whether two registers have the same (cardinal) number of elements.  At every stage, an element is in a register iff it was added but not removed.

Now, if we label each increment with the ordinal stage when it occurred, then
- the order type of the set of increments in a register equals the ordinal for that register.
- adding an element increments that ordinal
- liminf behavior follows. Since we do not have a copy instruction, the only discontinuity is that if a register was zeroed cofinally often, it is zero in the limit.

This question is in [Q/A format](https://stackoverflow.com/help/self-answer) as I was able to solve it before posting (with countable length added later), but feel free to contribute additional answers.  For example, an additional answer could have:
* More on bounded time computations.
* The minimum number of registers (and what happens with fewer registers).
* The spectrum of complexities of $Σ_1(\mathrm{Card})$ without the large cardinal assumption.

Comment: Your limit rules do not seem to be complete enough to determine the operation of the machines. For example, what happens if unboundedly often in a limit you had zeroed it and then begun incrementing again, to various heights each time before zeroing. What will the limit value be? Another issue is that by using the cardinality of $\alpha$, rather than $\alpha$ itself as an ordinal value, the operation of the machine will be different in different models of set theory, which might not agree on what is a cardinal.

Comment: See also this paper https://arxiv.org/abs/1310.5590 by Miha E. Habič concerning the cardinal-recognizing infinite time Turing machines, which investigate the complexity of ITTMs with a method of detecting cardinal stages.

Comment: @JoelDavidHamkins Thanks for the link.  If you zeroed cofinally often, the result is zero.  The elementary description is that each element has a distinct identity, but only their number matters.  Also, the dependence on cardinal values is in a certain sense unsatisfactory, but the description is simple.  With large cardinal axioms, we have absoluteness of finite output given finite input, and we can imagine using countable indiscernibles instead.

Comment: That behavior would align it with the liminf behavior of the Koepke machines and the other infinitary machines that are studied. My point was that this behavior does not follow from the description you had provided, and this is part of why I said your account of the machines was incomplete.

Comment: But another issue is your update rule with the cardinality, rather than the liminf used in the other models, makes your machines behave very strangely. For example, if a register is continually incremented in your machines, then at time $\omega$ it have value $\omega$, to be incremented, but I guess since $\omega+1$ has cardinality $\omega$, you keep value only $\omega$ after the increment? So once a register has infinite cardinality, then incrementing does nothing?

Comment: @JoelDavidHamkins You can think of increments as adding balls to a (set-theoretical) bag.  Once you have $ω$ balls in the bag, adding more will not change the number of balls inside until you have $ω_1$ balls.  I revised the posting to reduce the likelihood of confusion.

Comment: So the content of the registers somehow keeps going up to $\omega_1$, even though the register value stays at $\omega$ the whole time? And so at countable stages, the behavior is the same, whether or not we increment the register, but at time $\omega_1$ it jumps to $\omega_1$, but only if I have incremented uncountably many times? I don't think you've given a satisfactory account of how the machines work exactly.

Comment: Furthermore, since the macines hold only cardinals instead of ordinals in the registers, and without the ability to increment them like ordinals, I don't see how you can simulate the ordinal machines, as you claim in your answer. I expect that the cardinal machines (with a proper definition, not yet provided) may be significantly weaker than the ordinal register machines.

Comment: @JoelDavidHamkins I chose to phrase the question using minimal set theory, but an equivalent description is that the registers store and increment ordinals, but we can only test their equality as cardinals.  Let me know if I should expand some part of my answer.

Comment: Well, that is yet another machine model, which is significantly stronger in that capacity than the usual ordinal machines and I expect than the cardinal macines. For example, the ordinal register machines definitely cannot compute whether two ordinals have the same cardinality, since their operation is absoute between models of set theory, but equinumerosity of ordinals is not absolute in this way.  So definitely that machine model is not "an equivalent description" as you say.

Comment: @JoelDavidHamkins That model is the correct one, and I rephrased the question to avoid potential ambiguity.  Also, the generic absoluteness for cardinal register machines (conditional on large cardinal axioms) is not absoluteness in the number of steps taken but absoluteness in whether the machine halts assuming finite initial values in the registers.

Comment: OK, so your model has ordinals in the registers, but the branching instruction only tests for cardinal-equality, rather than ordinal-equality.  Are you claiming that you can nevertheless simultate the ordinal-equality test? You seem to claim this in your answer post. If so, could you explain how to do that?

Comment: I claim it is not possible to simulate the ordinal-equality test using the cardinal machines (which can only branch on cardinal-equality tests). To see this, observe by induction on the computation time that if the cardinalities of the ordinals in two machines are the same and they run the same program, then the program will perform exactly the same sequence of tasks in the two machines: this is true at each step and the hypothesis is preserved into limits. So there is no way for a cardinal machine to tell the difference between say $\omega^2+5$ in a register and $\omega^3+\omega$.

Comment: @JoelDavidHamkins Right.  If you replace all registers with the corresponding cardinals, the machine will never notice (at least, if you do that at most countably many times).  However, if a register stores $ω_α$, we can test (as shown in the answer) whether $α$ is a cardinal, and simulate ordinal register machines with the cardinality predicate that way.

Comment: @JoelDavidHamkins I have been meaning to ask you whether you are now satisfied that the description of cardinal register machines agrees with the computationally equivalent one using ordinals.  It is sometimes tricky to write a description that is simultaneously (1) broadly accessible, (2) intuitively natural/simple/motivated, and (3) unambiguously valid.

Comment: To be honest, I don't really find your description in the main post satisfactory. I would have found it much clearer for you to say explicitly that the registers hold ordinals, that you use the liminf rule for registers at limits, and that the programs are just like the ordinal register machine programs, except that you disallow copying from one register to another and you allow branching only on same-cardinality tests rather than same ordinality.  This all ultimately came out in the comments, but is not made clear in the original post.

Comment: Also, I find your statement that your cardinal machines simulate and are simulated by ordinal-register machines with a same-cardinality oracle to be not fully correct.  For example, as we noted in the comments, if your machines have some ordinals $\vec\alpha$ in the registers, then they are not able to simulate the operation of those other kinds of machines on those registers (unless the $\vec\alpha$ are all finite), because your machines can't tell if we replace the ordinals with others of the same cardinality.

Comment: It does seemt to be true, meanwhile, that if someone else sets up the coding $\alpha\mapsto\omega_\alpha$, then your machines can carry out the rest of the simulation, including the decoding part $\omega_\alpha\mapsto\alpha$. But this is somewhat less than what is usually meant by simulation, and it will break certain arguments about the strength of the machines.

Comment: Since you asked about presentational matters, if I were to be so bold as to make a suggestion, it would be that you focus less on making your description broadly accessible, and focus more on making your descriptions mathematically accurate.  It seems to me that your attempts as accessibility led you ultimately to sacrifice clarity for the experts. A mathematician should explain their ideas in as simple a way as possible, but not simpler.

Comment: Sorry, I meant $\omega+\alpha\mapsto\omega_\alpha$, which is the coding you used, although I think it would also work with $\alpha\mapsto\omega_\alpha$.

Comment: @JoelDavidHamkins Thanks for the feedback!  I revised both the question and the answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

*Unbounded Computations*

Independent of the restrictions, the halting problem is $Σ_1(\mathrm{Card})$-complete, where $\mathrm{Card}$ is the cardinality function (and $Σ_1$ is $Σ^V_1$).  Also, there are universal machines: For every $Σ_1(\mathrm{Card})$-predicate $P$ on $ℕ$, there is a cardinal register machine that halts iff $P(n)$ holds, where $n$ is the initial value in the first register.  The minimum number of registers might depend on the restrictions.

To start, we can test whether a condition occurred cofinally often (before the last limit state) by keeping a register nonzero most of the time, but setting it 0 and then 1 when the condition is met.  Thus, we can assume the more conventional liminf internal state at limit ordinals (and allowing that directly may cut down on the required number of registers).

Without an ordinal equality test, the machine will not notice if a register value is replaced with another ordinal of the same cardinality -- even if we replace multiple registers countably many times (without zeroing), and even if we have a copy instruction.

However, we can still simulate ordinal register machines with a predicate for cardinals (initial ordinals), with an ordinal $ω+α$ coded by $ω_α$ (which does not affect finite ordinals).  To convert $ω_α$ into $ω_{α+1}$, copy the register and keep incrementing the register until the copy and the register are no longer equal.  To check whether $α$ is a cardinal given a register $ω_α$: Copy $ω_α$ into register A, using register B to check when |A| has incremented, counting increments in register C, using register D to detect when C becomes a successor cardinal, and also checking whether C became a successor cardinal cofinally often.

Ordinal register machines can simulate arbitrary ordinal computation (without needing a copy/transfer instruction).  See "[Computing the Recursive Truth Predicate on Ordinal Register Machines](http://www.math.uni-bonn.de/people/koepke/Preprints/Computing_the_recursive_truth_predicate_on_ordinal_register_machines.pdf)" by Peter Koepke and Ryan Siders.  While the paper does not state it explicitly, their reduction shows that given an oracle (a class of ordinals) $F$, the halting problem for ordinal register machines with $F$ is $Σ_1(F)$-complete.

Thus, the halting problem for cardinal register machines is $Σ_1(\mathrm{Card})$-complete.  If $V=L$, this is $Σ_2$ complete, but under moderate large cardinal axioms, the complexity is in $Δ^1_3$.  Specifically, using the argument in [this question](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/279724/complexity-of-l-mathrmcf), $Σ_1(\mathrm{Card})$ corresponds to $Σ_2$ theory of the minimal inner model with a proper class of measurable cardinals if the sharp for this model exists.

*Note:* For models where the sharp does not exist, natural questions include whether $Σ_1(\mathrm{Card})$ captures the $Σ_2$ theory of K, and whether in some generic extension of V, it is $Σ_2$-complete.

*Countable Length Computations*

For countable length computations, there are three possibilities depending on the model.

- If we can test for ordinal equality, then these are just ordinal register machines, with $Σ^1_2$ complete halting problem.
- If we can test just for cardinal equality, then with a copy instruction, the complexity is equivalent to Infinite Time Register Machines, defined [here](http://www.math.uni-bonn.de/people/koepke/Preprints/An_enhanced_theory_of_infinite_time_register_machines.pdf).  That paper sets infinite liminf to 0, but that does not affect the expressiveness.  ITRM can compute $Π^1_1$ truth and more.  There are no universal machines; machine with more registers are more powerful.  As far as I know, which complexity class corresponds to ITRM is unknown.
- If we can test just for cardinal equality, then without a copy instruction, the complexity is exactly arithmetical (without universal machines).  While a copy instruction is not needed for unbounded ordinal/cardinal registers, its lack here prevents us from simulating a stack that resets at limits to unchanged variables rather than to 0.
  Proof sketch of arithmetical complexity: In one direction, arithmetical formulas can be evaluated recursively, with essentially one register per variable.  In the other direction, for a halting computation, at limit ordinals, at least one register will be $ω$ or 0, at limits of limit ordinals -- two registers, and so on, thus halting before $ω^ω$.  Because the state can be coded by an integer with the transition at the limits arithmetical, if time evolution over $α$-steps has an arithmetic formula, then so does time evolution over $αω$ steps.

Comment: Regarding the addendum, it seems to me that we should be able to simulate the infinite time register machines with your cardinal machines, since the ITRM require only finite numbers in their registers, and I think we can detect the overflow situation with your machines (see http://www.math.uni-bonn.de/people/koepke/Preprints/An_enhanced_theory_of_infinite_time_register_machines.pdf for an account of the machines). But if this is right, then we will be able to compute $\Pi^1_1$-complete sets, hence going strictly beyond the arithmetic sets, contrary to what you say.

Comment: @JoelDavidHamkins ITRM have the ability to copy contents of register A into register B, without zeroing register B first.  If cardinal machines were defined with this function, then countable time computability would correspond to ITRM.  This function is not needed for unbounded ordinal register machines.

Comment: Ah, I see. That is interesting.